# Typescript property does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am receiving this error for both list.item references:
client_1   | TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type 'List'.

Here is some relevant code. How do I work around this without setting it to any?

```
export interface List {
    createdAt: number;
    id: string;
    items: Array<ToDo>;
    updatedAt: number;
}
```

```
const emptyList = { createdAt: 0, id: '', items: [], updatedAt: 0 }
...
const [list, setList] = useState<List>(emptyList)
...
const filterList = <List extends any>(list: List) => {
    if (activeFilter === 'All') {
        return setFilteredTodos(list.items)
    }

    setFilteredTodos(list.items.filter((todo: ToDo) => todo.completed === filterMap[activeFilter as keyof object] as {}))
}
```

Comment: Remove `<List extends any>`. Why did you even add that?

Answer (score 2):

Writing `<List extends any>` before the function defines a generic type parameter with the (new) name `List` on the arrow function `filterList`.

To make it more clear, your code is equivalent to:

```
const filterList = <T extends any>(list: T) => { ... }
```

As you probably want to use the type `List` from above, you should remove the `<List extends any>` from the function assigned to `filterList`:

```
const filterList = (list: List) => { ... }
```